# How does SVG pattern and image width and height work?

Tags: svg

So I'm using SVG patterns ad im trying to figure out what width and height values I need. This is the example code. Also what is the x and y values for? Do I need x=0 and y=0 in my code?

```
    <defs>                              
        <pattern id="patt1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
            <image xlink:href="Images/pattern1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
```

Comment: Not if they are set to "0", because they default to zero anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your shape is a rect 20 units wide/high and your pattern is 10 units in size then there will be 4 copies of the pattern displayed in a 2 x 2 pattern.

x/y values allow the pattern to be offset within the shape.

Comment: so if I want only 1 copy then I need the pattern and image width and height to be the same?